# Packet monitoring on phone

Tags: data-monitoring

I suspect one of the apps on my phone is sending private data back to its servers. I'd like to analyze the traffic generated by this app. Specifically, I'd like to monitor the requests it's making (not the amount and destination but the parameters in each request). Is there any way to do this on my unrooted phone? I thought of connecting my phone and my laptop to the same WiFi network and then analyzing the traffic but since my laptop runs Win7 it seems it's not an easy thing to do (or maybe even not possible according to Wireshark's docs).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Connecting your phone and laptop to wifi should be the easiest way to do it. I was going to recommend WireShark too... why are you saying that you cannot do it?

Comment: The Wireshark docs say monitor mode is not possible in Windows http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN#Monitor_mode Do you know of a workaround?

Comment: Use a [Linux live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_live_CDs) like Knoppix then.